# Targeting specific property for transition delay

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am using the following CSS to animate features of a `div`. `.shrink` gets added to `.header` through Java

```
 .brand, .brand:visited, .brand:hover {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px; width: 100px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    background: url('img/logo.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.35s ease, width 0.35s ease, margin 0.35s ease, border-color 0.35s ease;
    -moz-transition: height 0.35s ease, width 0.35s ease, margin 0.35s ease, border-color 0.35s ease;
    -ms-transition: height 0.35s ease, width 0.35s ease, margin 0.35s ease, border-color 0.35s ease;
    -o-transition: height 0.35s ease, width 0.35s ease, margin 0.35s ease, border-color 0.35s ease;
    transition: height 0.35s ease, width 0.35s ease, margin 0.35s ease, border-color 0.35s ease;
}

header.shrink .brand {
   margin: 0; padding: 0;
   height: 80px; width: 80px;
   border-color: transparent;
}
```

I want to put a 0.35s delay on JUST the `border-color` transition. Not sure the proper notation so that it wont affect all values.

ALSO, is there a way to only have the delay applied in one direction? Meaning that I would like the delay to be applied when the border shows up, but no delay when it goes transparent.

Comment: Just add the delay to the last one alone (that is, like `..., border-color 0.35s 0.35s ease`).

Comment: oh cool I didn't think it was that easy, I added an addition to my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Question 1 - How to add a delay of 0.35s only to `border-color` property transition?**

It is very simple. Just add a delay in the last part of the comma separated values that is provided to the `transition` property (that is, the one for `border-color`) alone. In the shorthand when two time values are provided, the first would be considered as the duration and the second as the delay.

```
transition: height 0.35s ease, 
            width 0.35s ease, 
            margin 0.35s ease, 
            border-color 0.35s 0.35s ease; /* notice how the delay is added here alone */
```

**Question 2 - How to add a delay only when border shows up (on hover)?**

Again very simple, add two `transition` settings - one for the default selector and one for the `:hover` selector. In the one that is within `:hover` selector, add the delay because it applies when the `border` shows up and in the `transition` within the default selector do not provide any delay.

```css
.brand {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/100/100') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: height 0.35s ease, width 0.35s ease, margin 0.35s ease, border-color 0.35s ease;
}
.brand:hover {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  transition: height 0.35s ease, width 0.35s ease, margin 0.35s ease, border-color 0.35s 0.35s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class='brand'></div>
```